# Activities with Opportunities Report is not filtering

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

Hi friends i got a requirement like want to create a report how many activities are assigned to a single rep for opportunities.

I had tried to create a report using Activities with Opportunities Report in activities folder.

But I'm not getting "assigned to filter" in that report And It only Showing "Act On task" with subject line. I had created new report type for opportunities & activities And filtered based on last modified date in tasks but it is not working.

Comment: You may need to show a screen shot because I can easily do a report on activities by assignee (or all assignees) . The filter field name is `assigned`

Comment: Ya thanks But i resolved my issue because of role hierarchy i didn't get it.But I'm surprised even Salesforce admin is unable to create a report if he is in other role hierarchy @cropredy

Comment: actually, I had a similar issue recently with Opportunity Historical Trend reporting where, I , the sysad, couldn't see the data. Custom report types and visibility fully explained on [my blog](http://cropredysfdc.com/2016/04/14/historical-opportunity-trend-reporting-missing-opportunities/)

Comment: Thanks @cropredy till now i didn't seen your blog.But you are on of the best developers in stack overflow. So, now onwards i am regular follower of your blog cheers to you.

Comment: Pavan -- thanks for the kind words (StackExchange, maybe; StackOverflow, I'm not a contributor). By the way, if you want to read even smarter content, follow [Keith C's blog](https://force201.wordpress.com/)